# git: When branching off to rewrite lots of code, while others keep working - how to fuse the changes back?

Tags: git

So let's say Mike is rewriting lots of code because it had code smell. That means lots of classes get changed / created. Methods are extracted, created, and so on.
So he branches off into the "reworkclean" branch.

All others keep working in their respective feature branches. Or create new feature branches.

Now what should be the best way to merge things back together? Should Mike be the first to rebase his clean branch back. And the others follow and try to merge Mike's changes into their code? Or can everyone just keep finishing their features and merge them back and Mike will do the same when he is ready? Also merge or rebase?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You merge the repository. People don't do individual merges. It's very, very unclear

Answer (score -1):

Its always a good practice to work on branches. Its not required for Mike to push his code first. This wont work on a single day merge. So its better that end of each day everyone would push their code into respective branches, merge their code into master by taking a pull request, which will anyways list the conflicts before merge.

Generally, its better to go with "branch per feature" approach.